# Azure endpointName.azureedge.net error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Azure `endpointName.azureedge.net` created successfully but while accessing Endpoint url it show error

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Did I need to add Custom domain to work it out.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which endpoint do you add in Azure CDN profile? If adding Azure web app as its endpoint, which language do you use to develop your web app? From my experience, Please try to input detailed path in your url, for example https://endpointName.azureedge.net/default. We can also set default page at Azure web app Application settings like below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Build your solution in release mode
2. Try to publish it with using publish option of project then check

Comment: Or it is authorization related error which do not point me to login page?
if yes please guide me on how to allow ?